# Retain url hash value using Request.UrlReferrer

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have an list of paged results that is using AJAX requests to populate next/previous page clicks. I am using the jQuery history plugin to keep track of the page # the user is on. This basically appends http://site.com?query#pg=5 to the url.

If I click through to another page, I am trying to implement a Go Back button in the breadcrumb control. In trying to use:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

it seems that this does not preserve the # value at all. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is responsible for setting the HTTP_REFERER header and sending that to the server.  There has been research done for other questions on Stack Overflow (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183842/referrer-url-entire-url-including-parameters)) and it appears that none of the modern browsers send the hash value.

All is not lost, however.  A colleague of mine was faced with a similar situation and ended up setting up an AJAX call to the server to track the hash values on the server as well as the client.  It's a bit hack-y, but you can make it work.