# Getting a Parameter on The URL

Tags: html, url, variables, parameters

It's common to use URL parameters to show dynamic information, just like here on StackOverflow:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183842
```

But would that be possible when you're without any language like PHP or others? Is there any way to get that value using JavaScript and capture it inside a variable to present it like this:

```
<h1>param_variable</h1>
```

Comment: There is no (HTTP) parameter in the URL you posted.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467664/get-url-parameters-from-current-url-using-prototype-javascript/4467681#4467681) anser.

Comment: That's the type of parameter I need: `/1183842`, that looks like a folder and not like a parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window.location.href` contains the current URL. With some string manipulations you can grab anything you want from it.

In this case:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var id = url.split('/')[4];
alert(id);
```

Will alert

```
4479268
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can get the current page's url like this:

```
   var url = location.href;
```

You may then need to parse it your self to find the parameter that you are looking for.